# How to set phi per group using nlme in R?

Tags: r, nlme

When specifying a value as phi using `fixed = TRUE`, how can I set a fixed value for each Subject (e. g. value = 0.7 for Subject 1, value = 0.5 for Subject 2 etc.)?

```
library(nlme)
mod <- gls(rate ~ pressure,
           data = Dialyzer,
           corr = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Subject, value = 0.7, fixed = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With some work I can get this done in `glmmTMB`. I don't know how to do it in `nlme`, and I doubt it's possible (but don't know for sure).

Start by fitting the original model (a single fixed value of `phi`):

```r
library(nlme)
mod <- gls(rate ~ pressure,
           data = Dialyzer,
           corr = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Subject, value = 0.7, fixed = TRUE))
```

Warming up by doing this in `glmmTMB` and comparing:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
trans <- function(rho) rho/sqrt(1-rho^2)
g1 <- glmmTMB(rate ~ pressure + ar1(0+factor(index)|Subject), 
        dispformula = ~ 0, 
        map = list(theta = factor(c(1, NA))), 
        start = list(theta = c(0, trans(0.7))),
        data = Dialyzer)
```

What you need to know:

- the `ar1(0+factor(index)|Subject)` term in the formula is a subject-specific AR1 term (see the [relevant glmmTMB vignette](https://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/articles/covstruct.html) for a detailed explanation of how this works ["Construction of structured covariance matrices" section], and generally for many of the technical details underlying this answer)
- `trans()` is the transformation from the correlation scale to the internal parameterization of correlation coefficients in `glmmTMB`
- `dispformula = ~ 0` specifies that we have no additional residual variance term (this would be a *nugget effect* if we added it)
- `map` specifies which parameters to hold constant at their starting values, or set equal to each other: `theta` is the vector of random effect parameters (`glmmTMB` handles `ar1()` as a random effect), the first parameter is a log-SD, the second (to be held constant) is the autocorrelation parameter
- `start` specifies starting values (and, in particular, the fixed values for any parameters with their `map` element set to `NA`)

The results of the `glmmTMB` and `gls` models seem close enough (fixed effect parameters the same, covariance matrix within 2%, residual SD within 1%)

Now how do we hack this to get subject-specific fixed `phi` values? We'll generate 20 *different* `ar1()` terms, each of which applies only to a single subject, by multiplying each term by a 0/1 dummy (indicator) variable:

First fit the model with subject-specific terms, but with both SD and phi estimated and free to vary among subjects:

```r
dummy <- lme4::dummy
ar1_terms <- sprintf("ar1(0+dummy(Subject, %d):factor(index)|Subject)",
                     seq_len(length(levels(Dialyzer$Subject))))
form <- reformulate(c("pressure", ar1_terms), response = "rate")
g2 <- glmmTMB(form, dispformula = ~ 0, data = Dialyzer)
```

Partial results:

```
Subject    dummy(Subject, 1):factor(index)1  12.940   0.72 (ar1)
Subject.1  dummy(Subject, 2):factor(index)1  11.088   0.64 (ar1)
Subject.2  dummy(Subject, 3):factor(index)1   8.193   0.56 (ar1)
Subject.3  dummy(Subject, 4):factor(index)1   8.782   0.55 (ar1)
Subject.4  dummy(Subject, 5):factor(index)1   8.258   0.54 (ar1)
```

These seem plausible (SDs varying around 11.3, phi varying around 0.6).

Now little bit of hacking to set up the `map` and `start` vectors, which are 20 pairs of (log-SD, trans(phi)) corresponding to each Subject's parameters. The first element in each `map` pair should be 1 (so that the log-SD parameters for all subjects are set equal), and the second in each pair should be `NA` (to fix the value); the first element in each `start` pair is set to 0 (the default starting value for log-SD) and the second element in each `start` pair is `trans(phi_i)`. I set the fixed `phi` vector to `(0.4, 0.5, 0.6, ... 0.9, 0.4, ...)` for illustration.

```r
phivec <- rep((4:9)/10, length.out = 20)

## trick to get alternating (0, phi_i) pairs
startvec <- c(rbind(0, trans(phivec)))
## set all log-sd values equal, all phi values fixed to start values
mapvec <- factor(rbind(rep(1, 20), NA_integer_))
```

Now refit the model with this specification:

```r
g3 <- update(g2, start = list(theta = startvec), map = list(theta = mapvec))
```

The results seem to be what we expected.

```
Groups     Name                              Std.Dev. Corr      
Subject    dummy(Subject, 1):factor(index)1  11.66    0.40 (ar1)
Subject.1  dummy(Subject, 2):factor(index)1  11.66    0.50 (ar1)
Subject.2  dummy(Subject, 3):factor(index)1  11.66    0.60 (ar1)
Subject.3  dummy(Subject, 4):factor(index)1  11.66    0.70 (ar1)
Subject.4  dummy(Subject, 5):factor(index)1  11.66    0.80 (ar1)
Subject.5  dummy(Subject, 6):factor(index)1  11.66    0.90 (ar1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in R, but I believe you can use the `corFixed` argument and the `corClasses` function to achieve what you're looking for so let me explain using an example.

First, let's say you want to define a custom correlation structure function called `custom_corAR1`,this function takes a vector of fixed values as an argument and inside the function, you can create the `corStruct` with the AR1 correlation structure and set the fixed values using the `value` argument.

To specify the correlation structure using `corClasses`, you can pass the custom `corAR1` function along with the fixed values vector to the `corAR1` argument and additionally, you can indicate that the correlation structure is fixed by setting `corFixed` to "corAR1"!

check this out:

```
library(nlme)

fixed_values <- c(0.7, 0.5) #replace this with the desired fixed values for each subject

custom_corAR1 <- function(value) {
  corStruct(AR1(form = ~ 1 | Subject),
            value = value,
            fixed = TRUE)
}

mod <- gls(rate ~ pressure,
            data = Dialyzer,
            corr = corClasses(corAR1 = custom_corAR1(fixed_values),
                              corFixed = "corAR1"))
```

Comment: In my opinion,this seems to be a bug that should be fixed eventually. the correct answer has been provided by dear @BenBolker, but I'm confused as to why I have been awarded 500 points?! A while ago, I participated in a bounty and despite the fact that the points were supposed to be awarded to me and my answer was correct, they were given to someone else. I even raised this issue with the support team of this website, but they said there was nothing they could do about it. I apologize to BenBolker on my behalf.